# Can Biicode publish to a local server (behind the firewall)?

Tags: biicode

I'm looking at BiiCode for our C++ code, but it appears that you must use the BiiCode cloud as a host.  Is there a way in which you keep your dependencies (internal libraries in our case) on a local server?  Our team doesn't like having code outside the firewall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet. Biicode will go open source soon, so you might have to wait until that. We are working on a feature for premium accounts to locally encrypt contents, so the encrypted passwords never hit the server.

*(Disclaimer: I work at biicode).*

Comment: Thanks!  That helps with the decision.

Comment: Have you fiddle with biicode? Your thoughts may help biicode become your best fit when open source!

Comment: I have not used biicode.  We're doing a high level comparison of similar products currently.  It sounds as though you plan to offer encrypted, private feeds hosted by biicode.  We are looking for a solution which allows us to host private packages internally (behind the firewall).  So far, the only solutions which seem to allow that are NuGet & CPM.  However, maintenance on NuGet's C++ tools appears to be waning, and CPM just fetches from a git repo.  So, there is definitely a gap to be filled.